# Laravel date format and consoletv

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to produce some charts for my laravel website but I am new to date formatting and I don't get this code, can someone help me to figure out how to tweak it to show graph per year ?

```
$project = Project::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"), date('Y'))->get();

$chart = Charts::database($project, 'bar', 'highcharts')
    ->title("Monthly new Logged-in Students")
    ->elementLabel("Total Students")
    ->dimensions(1000, 500)
    ->responsive(true)
    ->groupByYear(date('Y'), true);

return view('coordinator.Graph1', compact('chart'));
```

I really don't get this part

```
(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))
```

if someone could explain it to me I would be able to group it by year successfully

Comment: maybe try  to use whereYear ?

Comment: where I try it?

Comment: Project::whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->get();

Comment: What chart library are you using?

Comment: now iam not sure groupByYear is a package function where your column must be named year or what

Comment: use carbon  insted

Comment: I use ConsoleTv library

Comment: @Boni can you help with an example how to use the carbon ?

Comment: of course, I will help you

Comment: are you there @ALIISMAEEL please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller

```
use Carbon;
```

then you can use carbon in your query

```
$project = Project::where('created_at','=',Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->get();
```